# How can a Thread constructor can accept a run method directly?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was refering to DeadLock code and saw this website

http://www.javatpoint.com/deadlock-in-java

I saw the java API, but couldn't find any such Thread Constructor and still wondering how is this being compiled in Eclipse IDE ??

```
Thread t1 = new Thread() {

    public void run() {  
        synchronized (resource1) {  
            System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 1");  

            try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}  

            synchronized (resource2) {  
                System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 2");  
            }  
        }  
    }  
};
```

How can a Thread constructor can accept a run method directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor isn't *accepting* a `run` method (e.g., as an argument), that code is creating an *anonymous class*, see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). Behind the scenes, a class with no name (anonymous class) is created that derives from `Thread` and overrides the `run` method; then an instance of that class is created and assigned to the `t1` variable.

---

Just for completeness, though: As of Java 8, it *is* possible for the `Thread` constructor to (in effect) accept a `run` function as an argument, because of Java 8's lambda functions. That looks like this:

```
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("Running");
    });
```

This is possible because `Thread` has a constructor accepting a [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) instance, and `Runnable` is a *functional interface* (an interface that only defines a single function), and so you can create an instance implementing that interface simply by using a lambda and then pass that into the `Thread` constructor. There's a tutorial on lambdas [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). But that's not what the quoted code is doing.

Here's the code in your question using a lambda instead of an anonymous class:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
    synchronized (resource1) {  
        System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 1");  

        try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}  

        synchronized (resource2) {  
            System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 2");  
        }  
    }  
});
```

Comment: it is not true, that anonymous class have no name. It is auto-generated name, and you can find it via reflection. Example `AnonymousName$1`

Comment: @T.G: Yes, but that's an implementation detail. At a high level, they don't have names; if that weren't the intent, they wouldn't be called anonymous classes (as anonymous means "no name").

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: that's true. I just thought, it is worth mentioning, that theirs names exists :)